# Stop a CSS3 Animation at the last frame of the iteration-count

Tags: css, animation, sass

I've setup a pen at http://codepen.io/samaxes/pen/KbCHi with a pie timer.

However I haven't figured out how I to stop the animation at the last frame of the iteration-count (0.9 in this particular example).

Adding the following CSS property:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

will not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really. However, if you set the animated objects to the state you want them to end up in, it's relatively easy to get the effect you're looking for:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@mixin timer($item, $duration, $size, $color, $end, $hover: pause) {
  #{$item}, #{$item} * { @include box-sizing(border-box); }

  #{$item} { 
    width: $size;
    height: $size;
  }

  #{$item} .pie {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background: $color;
  }

  #{$item} .spinner {
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%;
    z-index: 200;
    transform: rotate(360deg*.9);
    animation: rota $duration + s linear $end;
  }

  #{$item}:hover .spinner,
  #{$item}:hover .filler, 
  #{$item}:hover .mask {
    animation-play-state: $hover;
  }

  #{$item} .filler {
    border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 0 50% 50% 0; 
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
    animation: opa $duration + s steps(1,end) $end reverse;
  }

  #{$item} .mask {
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: 300;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: opa $duration + s steps(1,end) $end;
  }

  @keyframes rota {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    90% { transform: rotate(360deg*.9); }
  }

  @keyframes opa {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    50%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  }
}

@include timer('.wrapper', 5, 250px, #6c6, 0.9);
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/hisHj)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with other values, please try replacing the value .9 with .3 (and 90% with 30%).

Comment: Here. Working with 30%: http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/hisHj . You don't need `.filler` or `opa` if it's less than 50% because of how you set it up.