# Make CSS Hover state remain after "unhovering"

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a small issue that I've never really had to deal with before. I'm a beginner web designer, and I recently used the CSS hover feature on a div on my webpage. Another image is revealed when one hovers over this div; however, the new image disappears when you "unhover", and I would like it to stay visible.

Here is an example of the code that I am using:

```
#about {
height: 25px;
width: 84px;
background-image: url('about.png');
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 0px;
}

#onabout {
height: 200px;
width: 940px;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 0px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 300;
display: none;
}

#about:hover #onabout {
display: block;
}
```

Is there any way to solve this using just CSS? I haven't used any javascript thus far and I'm not very comfortable with it.

Either way, any solutions will be gladly accepted! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 49):

Here i go with my CSS idea.

You may use transition-delay;
http://jsfiddle.net/nAg7W/

```
div img {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition:0s 180s;
}
div:hover img {
    opacity:1;
    transition:0s;
}
div {
    line-height:1.2em;
    font-size:1em;
    color:black;
    transition:0s 180s;
}
div:hover {
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    transition:0;
}
```

markup:

```
<div>some text to hover to see an image wich is hidden as you read this
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=zi image" />
```

it could be possible as well, to click, so it fades away.
http://jsfiddle.net/nAg7W/1/

```
div:hover img:focus {/* includes tabindex in html tag for img */
   opacity:0;
   transition:3s;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg) scale(0.23);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg) scale(0.23);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg) scale(0.23);
   -o-transform:rotate(-360deg) scale(0.23);
   -ms-transform:rotate(-360deg) scale(0.23);
   transform:rotate(-360deg) scale(0.23);
}
```

Comment: in this example, image remain on screen 3 mns after mouse left its div area. almost an eternity, that you can shorten or make last even longer :)

Answer (score 28):

As @[Leo Pflug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2834652/leo-pflug) indicates, you can do this with some confidence in **CSS and HTML *on and after click*** by using the techniques detailed here http://cssconf.com/talk-seddon.html.

With a dash of **JavaScript**, it's possible and simple and reliable, as shown by @[Wind Shear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/698661/wind-shear).

**Pure CSS *on and after hover***, however, is a lot more difficult and, depending on what browsers you need to support, not possible in a currently production-viable way.  The problem is that anything you change with the :hover pseudo-class selector will not (and/or should not) match elements over which you are no longer hovering.

The only way you are likely to be able to do this with pure CSS is with CSS3 Animations.  To that end, I have created a demo **http://cdpn.io/GLjpK** (v2 w/FF & IE) that uses CSS animations to swap to a hover state on hover and then persist that state until the page is reloaded.

```
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    // normal styles
  }
  100% {
    // hover styles
  }
}

.class {
  animation-name: hover;
  animation-duration: 1ms;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;      
}

.class:active,
.class:focus,
.class:hover {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

I tested in it Chrome latest, Firefox latest, and IE 10.  Worked in all three.

Note I had some trouble with codepen not displaying the latest saved code, so I created a fresh one here **http://cdpn.io/GLjpK**.

See [Stop a CSS3 Animation at the last frame of the iteration-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644246/stop-a-css3-animation-at-the-last-frame-of-the-iteration-count) and [Stopping a CSS3 Animation on last frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359627/stopping-a-css3-animation-on-last-frame) for what/why/how.

**UPDATE: Lea Verou has now also demonstrated this technique** in her post [Smooth state animations with animation-play-state](http://lea.verou.me/2014/01/smooth-state-animations-with-animation-play-state/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the only solution that works perfectly without javascript.

Answer (score 15):

You can't permanently stay as hover state using CSS as it merely defines the rules on styling the tags, classes, IDs, pseudo-classes, and states. So unfortunately, you need Javascript to solve the problem.

Being a fan of [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) (hehehe), here is my solution.

### CSS

```
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li.permahover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

### Javascript using jQuery

```
$("#onabout").one("mouseover", function() {
  $("#onabout").addClass('permahover');
});
```

The `one` event attaches a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most **once** per element.

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/w83BW/

Answer (score 7):

It will have to be done with JavaScript, using jquery you can permanently add the style like this:

```
$(#onabout).onmouseover().css("display","block");
```

Comment: I second this. Don't be afraid to try using javascript just because you're not comfortable with it. You can't learn without trying :) In this case CSS cannot do what you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript

Answer (score 4):

### Some Pure CSS Ideas

I'm not quite sure what you intend by "stay visible." Here are some differing thoughts based off your possible purposes, but each has possible side effects not intended. The only purely permanent solution is going to be through javascript (as others have noted).

**Longer 'Stay' But Still Not Permanent**

If you mean stay visible as long as *one might also be hovering over the revealed image itself*, then a simple change in your code will work:

```
#about:hover #onabout,
#onabout:hover {
   display: block;
}
```

**Permanent 'Stay'**

If you wrap your `#onabout` in a `position: fixed` wrapper *that is also revealed on hover*, and set that wrapper to fix to the top, right, bottom, and left of the screen, then use that wrapper's `:hover` to keep the `#onabout` it will stay permanently. But it is also going to be in a fixed position relation, and other hover events or clicks may be prevented. That is likely not desirable, but again, I don't know your specific application, so it is possible that the idea would work for you. You would actually set the `display: block` as default on the `#onabout` and hide it through the wrapper. Code for the wrapper and the hover would be something like:

```
#permaHoverWrap {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: none;
}

#about:hover #permaHoverWrap,
#permaHoverWrap:hover {
   display: block;
}
```

Since the `#onabout` is in the `#permaHoverWrap` in this solution, it becomes visible through the display of the fixed wrapper, and then stays that way through the guaranteed hover of that wrapper. Again, the side effects of this solution could be too severe except under the right circumstances. However, as a proof of concept, it can be done purely through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is adding or removing classes to an element like this(done with JQUERY)

```
#about {
height: 25px;
width: 84px;
background-image: url('about.png');
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 0px;
}

#onabout {
height: 200px;
width: 940px;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 0px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 300;
display: none;
}

#about.hover #onabout {
display: block;
}
```

notice that I chang :hover to .hover(Class Name)

```
$("#about").hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: But this will pointlessly execute the `eventHandler` on mouse-in, and mouse-out. I think OP should rather `.one( events [, data ], handler(eventObject) )` http://api.jquery.com/one/ (even tho he asked for a css-only solution)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any possibility to do this with :hover, when relying on pure css.
If you insist on using css, you might change it to clicking. So that when the user clicks on the div, the other one gets shown permanently.
Like this:

```
<style>
.onabout
{
    display: none;
}

input#activate
{
    display: none;
}

input#activate:checked + .onabout
{
    display: block;
}
</style>

<label for="activate">
    <div class="about">Click me</div>
</label>
<input id="activate" type="checkbox"></input>
<div class="onabout">Visible while checkbox:checked true or Radiobutton:checked true</div>
```

checkbox makes you able to click it away. if you don't want that check the input type to radio.

Answer (score 1):

One can apparently use CSS animation, with an infinite delay to handle this. See an article here...
http://joelb.me/blog/2012/maintaining-css-style-states-using-infinite-transition-delays/

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to come across the answer to your question. See example css below:

```
.Top_body_middle_headings_subtitle {
margin-top: 35px;
margin-left: 25px;
font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
font-size: 12pt;
color: #C77F0D;
transition: 600ms 3s;
}

or

.Top_body_middle_headings_par {
margin-top: 4px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 25px;
font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
font-size: 9pt;
color: #745D26;
position: relative;
top: -30px;
left: -205px;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2.5s 3s, left 600ms 3s, top 1.5s 3s;
}
```

the second number/entry on the transition feature acts as a release function. 
In effect, your hover transition(s) will take place and not revert back to normal until after the period of time quoted in the second entry (transition: 600ms 3s; - This example would represent your mouse virtually not hovering off the element for 3s).

Hope this helps.

K.P.U

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need Javascript as many in this thread suggest. Here's how to do it with CSS alone:

(You need to use visibility instead of display)

```
.btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: all 0s ease 1s; /*delay 1s*/
  visibility: hidden;
}
.btn-group:hover .dropdown-menu {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery solution that hovers over a second level menu item and persistently shows the child third level until you hover over another second level item.

```
 $("ul.second > li.dropdown").hover(function() {
    // remove the show class if it exists
    $('ul.third').removeClass('show');
    // add the show class only to this child
    $(this).find('.third').addClass('show');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
#about:hover #onabout {
 display: block;
}
```

Add this line:

```
#onabout:hover {
 display: block;
}
```

So the final code will be like this:

```
#about:hover #onabout,
#onabout:hover {
 display: block;
}
```

just make sure you didn't add margin.