# JS permanent hover state with radio button behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to use [user Wind Shear's permanent hover solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17100334/834788) on a group of thumbnails.  However, I'd like the "permanent hover" state to only be applied to one thumbnail at a time.  So if I hover off a thumbnail and onto the page the permanent hover stays applied to that thumbnail, but when I hover onto a different thumbnail it should take the permeant hover off the first thumbnail and apply it to the new one.

html:

```
<ul class="test">
    <li id="onabout">
        <a href="">Alpha</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Hiya! And it persists</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$("#onabout").one("mouseover", function() {
    $("#onabout ul").addClass('permahover');
});
```

css:

```
ul {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

ul li {
    display: block;
}

ul li a {
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
}

ul li a {
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li ul.permahover {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle from Wind Shear's question: http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/w83BW/

The permanent hover function works great, but I can't figure out how to modify it to only apply to one thumbnail at a time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.on` instead of `.one` and remove the class then add it to the hovered element

```
$(".onabout").on("mouseover", function() {
  $('.permahover').removeClass('permahover');
  $(this).find("ul").addClass('permahover');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w83BW/34/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()` instead of `.one()`

```
$("#onabout").on("mouseover", function() {
    $("#onabout ul").removeClass('permahover');
    $(this).find("ul").addClass('permahover');
});
```