# hover without returning to normal state

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a question on the `:hover` state. Can I stop my transition from turning back to the original state after stopping the `mouseover`.

```
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin: 150px;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s; 
}

div:hover {
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(1440deg);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arJbn/)

That is what I have, but I don't know what to add to stop the whole thing in circle-state.
I just want the `:hover` pseudo-class to start it.

Comment: Can we see this on jsfiddle please

Comment: It's not that hard to make one yourself. He's lazy, don't be one yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/U3nw4/

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering

Comment: you cannot do it with `:hover`, the state will be turned back if it's not `:hover`. Using script instead.

Comment: @KingKing he doesn't want the element to revert back to square. He wants to keep it in circle after it was hovered once.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I mistyped **can** while it should be **cannot**. Hence I said ***using script instead***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript. Add a class on hover, and set the CSS rules as follows:

```
element {
    transition: ....;
    old: state;
}

element.hovered-once {
    news: state;
}
```

The transition will activate when the class get applied, and just don't remove the class when mouse is out.