# CSS Menu on hover selector

Tags: css, menu, hover, onhover

I am very close. How can I have MENU 1 on my `.`[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/king2525/64nmpjyh/) display as the default menu option then change when MENU 2 on hover?

Thank you in advance. Keep coding! :)

Comment: Your fiddle already works right?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Praveen Kumar, the fiddle works however I am having trouble on having MENU 1 display on default. On hover on MENU 2, hide MENU 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit this entirely away from jquery based on your response do the following:

1. Change `#submenu1` from `display:none;` to `display: block;`
   This will Show your first menu by default.
2. Add the following css section

   > `#a2:hover ~ #submenu1 {
   >      display: none;
   >    }`

The `~` character selects #submenu1 when you hover over a2 element. Then it changes it to display:none;. Since you have code already to set submenu2 to display when you hover over a2, all this does is hide the submenu1 element.

Comment: Thank you Todd. I would like to have it powered by CSS only.

Comment: @Elvis I have updated my response based on this. Much simpler and I learned something too!

Comment: Just a quick note: if this worked for you, can you mark it as the accepted answer? :) Thanks @Elvis !

Comment: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/king2525/64nmpjyh/3/) When I hover over MENU 2 then hover over to ITEM2, ITEM2 changes to ITEM 1. Thank you.

Comment: can you help with the request above?

Comment: Hey @Elvis, I will look at the issue and try and write something up tomorrow. I see what you mean though. Perhaps some sort of delay can fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering may be relevant

Comment: Hi @Todd, can you please help this morning? Thank you