# CSS Transition - get return animation, different from start css property

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#i {
height: 20px;
background-color: #999;
/*return animation*/
-webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
}

#i:hover {
height: 300px;
background-color: #F00;

/*begin animation*/
-webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="c" id="i" >Hover Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See above. How do I get the box 'hover me' to end its bck-color to red, on the /*return animation*/, using only CSS. It understandably returns to #999, but I dont want that.

Basically: Start box 20px, #999 >> expand 300px >> Contract 20px, #red

---

Also is there a way to pass a value to a css property when using transitions like this:

```
-webkit-transition: background-color:red 0.4s ease-in 0.3s
```

Thanks for your help. Just trying to understand the very basics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make CSS Hover state remain after "unhovering"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering)

Comment: What you need is `animation`, not `transition`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something very close (but maybe not enough) using CSS animations.

Set an animation (not transition) on the element, and pause it. Set it's fill mode to `forwards`. On hover set the animation to running. When the animation ends, the end state remains.

The caveat - if somebody stops hovering before the animation is done, it will remain in it's current position until hovered again.

```css
#i {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #999;
  animation: animation 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
#i:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes animation {
  0 {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #999;
  }
  50% {
    height: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c" id="i">Hover Me</div>
```

Comment: Dori ...Dang it caveat. Pretty close. Im guessing you cant pause it on 50% on hover? ...or is there a way? Let me know.

Comment: Sorry - nothing that I can think about.

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't have anything like this right now, you probably use JavaScript to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a combination of jquery add and remove classes. wishing it could have been pure css though.*sigh*

Hopefully this simple code helps someone. If anyone has something better esp with pure css... id be happy to learn. @obi Cheers and thanks to all.

```
    <body>
    <div class="c" id="i" >Hover Me</div>
    <style>

    .c {height: 20px; background-color: #999;}

    /*----begin animation-----------------------------------*/
    #i:hover {
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #0F0;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;

    }

    /*----return animation-----------------------------------*/
    .c_returnAnime {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #F00; 
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;
        transition: height 0.3s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.3s;

    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $('#i').hover(
            //always add class before removing other or errors
            function(){ $(this).addClass('c_returnAnime') }, 
            function(){ $(this).removeClass('c') }
    )
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```