# changing css property with hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I'm trying to move an object to another part of the page with hover. The problem is that I want it to stay at the new position even after my cursor is no longer pointing at that object.
*Is there any way to change css properties permanently using **css only**?*

for examle, the object im trying to move has the id "movingFly"
(It's a div with just the letter E in it)

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
@font-face{

font-family:fly1;
 src:url('Insects.ttf');

}
#movingFly {
  font-family: fly2;
  font-size: 150px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#movingFly:hover {
  transform: translate(200px, 100px);
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="movingFly">E</div>
```

I've tried using transform to re-position it but it won't stay in its new position after moving the cursor from it.

Comment: Maybe this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering

Comment: Basically "NO"....Not without a lot of work.

Comment: And even if you did get it to "work", it's not going to be nice.