# How Do I Keep the Last Hovered Item Active?

Tags: html, css

So, I got this code the works like Tabs opening the content when each tab is hovered. So when the user removed the mouse, they close automatically. How would I go to make the content of the last hovered Tab to remain open?

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.tab {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 10px;
}

#tab1:hover+#content1,
#tab2:hover+#content2,
#tab3:hover+#content3 {
  display: block;
}

#tab1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#tab2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
}

#tab3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div id="content1" class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    Tab 3
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: change opacity  see on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `.last` class when you hover a tab, and only remove it when another tab is hovered.

```js
var $tabs = $('.tab');
$tabs.hover(function() {
  $tabs.not($(this)).removeClass('last');
  $(this).addClass('last');
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.tab {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 10px;
}

#tab1:hover+#content1,
#tab2:hover+#content2,
#tab3:hover+#content3,
.last + .content {
  display: block;
}

#tab1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#tab2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
}

#tab3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab1" class="tab">
  Tab 1
</div>
<div id="content1" class="content">
  1
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
  Tab 2
</div>
<div id="content2" class="content">
  2
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
  Tab 3
</div>
<div id="content3" class="content">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Simple, and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LeonFreire awesome, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

**Let's try this:** with simple jquery function

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.tab', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var self = $(this),
          ref = self.attr('ref');
    
      $('.content').hide();
      $('#' + ref).fadeIn();
    
    })
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.tab {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background: #ccc;
  padding:15px;
  min-height:400px; width:100%;
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 10px;
}



#tab1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#tab2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
}

#tab3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab1" ref="content1" class="tab">
      Tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="content1" class="content">
      <b>Tab 1 Content</b>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" ref="content2" class="tab">
      Tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="content2" class="content">
      <b>Tab 2 Content</b>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" ref="content3" class="tab">
      Tab 3
    </div>
    <div id="content3" class="content">
      <b>Tab 3 Content</b>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseover`, `mouseleave` events, `.filter()`, `.next()`, `.not()`, `.show()`, `.hide()`

```js
$("[id^=tab]").on({"mouseover": function() {
  $("[id^=content]").hide().filter($(this).next()).show()
}, "mouseleave": function() {
  $("[id^=content]").not($(this).next()).hide()
}})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.tab {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 10px;
}
/*
#tab1:hover+#content1,
#tab2:hover+#content2,
#tab3:hover+#content3 {
  display: block;
}
*/
#tab1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#tab2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
}

#tab3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div id="content1" class="content">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="content">
    2
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    Tab 3
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="content">
    3
  </div>
</body>
```