# Is there a way to make the ":hover" stay?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the `:hover` comment stay even after you leave the mouse from being over it?

Example of something that doesn't work because of it:

```css
#SS {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://media1.tenor.com/images/a8479ab2587f60773c0032ada0c85d3b/tenor.gif?itemid=5751040);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}

#SS:hover {
  transform: translate(500px);
}

#SS p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 140%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  padding-top: 265px;
}
```

```html
<div id="SS">
  <p>You will never catch me!!!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: I'm new to this so I have started to learn html and css first, but I would love to see an answer with js, because I want to learn it as soon as I finish with css

Comment: It's possible with css only but depends on the user case, you have an answer for it here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with JS, I'd suggest using this one:

```js
var ss = document.getElementById('SS');

ss.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  //ss.classList.add('SS-hover');
  ss.classList.toggle('SS-hover');
})
```

```css
#SS {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://media1.tenor.com/images/a8479ab2587f60773c0032ada0c85d3b/tenor.gif?itemid=5751040);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}

.SS-hover {
  transform: translate(500px);
}

#SS p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 140%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  padding-top: 265px;
}
```

```html
<div id="SS">
  <p>You will never catch me!!!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it go back so every time you try to touch it will run away from you?

Comment: You can use `classList.toggle` for that, updated the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in various ways. for example:
//Html

```
  <div id="SS" onmouseover="translateSS(this)">
      <p>You will never catch me!!!</p>
  </div>
```

//JS

```
 function translateSS(x) {
            x.style.transform = "translate(500px)";
            }
```