# How to show span on hover and then not hide when not hovered?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example jsfiddle which displays the span content when hovered over it.
I want it not to hide when it is not hovered.
It should hide when clicked somewhere outside.

http://jsfiddle.net/jn6re3aq/1/

```css
#myChart {
  background-color: black;
}

#tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

#graphs:hover #tooltip {
  display: block;
}

#graphs {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="graphs">
  <span id="tooltip">thisistest</span>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="550" height="350"></canvas>
</section>
```

Comment: In my opinion only possible to achieve with Javascript. CSS does not know a click(ed) function.

Comment: I tried using `:active` property but it is still getting hidden when not hovered.

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria As far as I know, there isn't a pure CSS solution for this, but you should use JavaScript.

Comment: Please [search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+stay+after+hover+site:stackoverflow.com) before asking

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with css, you have to use either javascript or jquery, simply on hover change the display to block.

Here is an example using jquery:

```js
$("#graphs").hover(function(){
  $("#tooltip").css("display","block");
});
```

```css
#myChart{
    background-color: black;
}
#tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #333;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    opacity: 0.8; 
    width: 300px;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}

#graphs{
 background-color: red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="graphs">
    <span id="tooltip">thisistest</span>    
    <canvas id="myChart" width="550" height="350"></canvas>
</section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering

Comment: @mplungjan try stopping at the text, it will give an unwanted behavior, hence until this time the best way of doing this is by JS/jQuery.