# Make css :hover style not go away

Tags: css

So I am looking for a way to introduce some new CSS whenever an element has been clicked, and then have that stay afterwards. It's really the last part that I can't get to work.

Here's my code so far:

HTML

```html
<body>
    <p>Click me</p>
</body>
```

---

CSS

```
#elmt:active{
   background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

So I want the background color to stay light green from whenever you click the `#elmt` the first time, and not go back to the default color when you release the mouse.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not with css alone, you will need to add/remove classes with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle a css class on click pretty easily with a bit of javascript:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', 
  (e) => e.target.classList.toggle('active')
);
```

```css
.active {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p>Click me</p>
<p>Or me</p>
```

As [Stephen P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) points out in [a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588709/make-css-hover-style-not-go-away/69588840?noredirect=1#comment123001611_69588840) you'll want to be more selective about which elements you target--in the snippet above you can toggle the background on `body` if you click between the paragraphs, for example--but this was just a quick proof of concept.

Comment: This is absolutely the strategy I'd use but, Tobias, be aware that once you start nesting elements things get a little more complicated. Try it with a list `<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>` you'll find you can toggle the individual `li` elements but you can also toggle the `ul` itself.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do that with css only

```
//get your element 
document.getElementById("#elmt").addEventListener("click", (e)>{
// get the other element 
document.getElementById("#theOtherName").style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your element is not a focusable element, you need to add the tabindex attribute, so it can catch the click event , and be clicked,focused and active.

Once the clicking part is solved, you can add a transition-delay of a lifetime on the regular state, so it seems like style remains.

exemple (duplicate of : [Make CSS Hover state remain after "unhovering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering/17101357#17101357) ):

```css
p[tabindex] {
  transition-duration: 0;
  transition-delay: 99999s;
}

p[tabindex]:active {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0">Click me</p>
```