# How to make an overlay invisible until hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I'm trying to make my overlay invisible until I hover over a picture (`<img>`):

```html
<div class="channel-picture">
  <img class="profile-picture" src="channel-pictures/channel-1.jpeg">

  <div class="channel-picture-overlay">
    <img class="channel-picture-overlay-image" src="channel-pictures/channel-1.jpeg">
    <p class="p1-overlay">
      Marques Brownlee
    </p>
    <p class="p2-overlay">
      15M Subscribers
    </p>
  </div>
  </div
```

I tried to use css; I want to make the overlay invisible until I hover over the channel-picture.

```
.channel-picture:hover {
    /* and here i want to add my overlay to appear */
}
```

Comment: `I tryed use in css` did you try opacity ? or what have you tried with CSS ? Please share your code

Comment: how you want add little bit more detail, if possible output image

Comment: once you the hover is removed, do you want overlay to be hidden again?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502693/14862885) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047948/14862885) S.O answers

- Here we use `~` operator to select your `.channel-picture-overlay`, when your `.profile-picture` is hovered(Change the selector element names in code if needed).
  Get help over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502693/14862885) to learn about usage of selector's operators.
- We use transition along with a value `9^(9^9)`, which is highest value, with three digits,no computer has found yet! Get amazed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=9%5E%289%5E9%29)
- We use opacity currently, just comment those lines and uncomment nearby lines, if you want to use display instead. *Homework: difference between using `opacity:0%`, `display:none`!*

```css
.channel-picture-overlay{
    opacity:0%; /*display:none;*/
    transition: 0s calc((9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9)*1s);
}
.profile-picture:hover ~ .channel-picture-overlay{/*Change this selector if needed*/

    opacity:100%; /*display:block;*/
    transition: display 0s 0s; /*transition: display 0s 0s;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-picture">
  <img class="profile-picture" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/400/200">

  <div class="channel-picture-overlay">
    <img class="channel-picture-overlay-image" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100/100">
    <p class="p1-overlay">
      Marques Brownlee
    </p>
    <p class="p2-overlay">
      15M Subscribers
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
```