# Run animation scale and infinity rotate at the same time on Hover

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create an animation where a link will have a scaled background colour and an infinite rotating animation when hovered over it. I've tried to combine the two animations, but for some reason, it doesn't work. Here's the code I've tried to reproduce. Can someone tell me how to achieve the desired animation?

**Desired effect:**

On hover, instantly show the after pseudo-element with a scale effect, and at the same time, keep the border rotating on itself.

```css
body{
 background:black;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 width:100%;
 height:100vh
}
.full-rounded-link {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #191F2A;
    border-color: #191F2A;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
.full-rounded-link a {
 color:white
}
.full-rounded-link::before {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
    z-index: -1;
    border: 1px dashed #fff;
}
.full-rounded-link:hover::before { 
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite , dance 0.5s ease ;
}
.full-rounded-link:not(:hover)::before {
  animation: scale-down 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes scale-down {
  0% {
transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes dance {
 0% {
  transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(-360deg);
 }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
   transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
  100% {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="full-rounded-link">
        <a  href="/my-link">
          a link
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more info on what is the desired result?
Because if you will uncomment this line:  /*animation: spin 10s linear infinite;*/, looks like it is rotating and growing, so can't understand what is exactly not working.

Comment: in your keyframe  change this

@keyframes spin { 
   0% {
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-360deg);
  }

Comment: both animation are working hover your link and see red color take some time then it will show because scale is 0 to 1 and time is 10s

Comment: i update the code and add the desired effect, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.full-rounded-link:hover::before {
 transform: scale(1);
 animation: spin 10s linear infinite, dance 2s linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes dance {
 0% {
  transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(-360deg);
 }
}
```

Comment: this is partialy work thanks , could you please comment why ? thanks

Comment: first i separated the animation because i assumed you wanted the circle to fill in red and then start spinning, i also removed infinite from the second animation because i wanted it to stay in red instead of repeating over & over

Comment: thanks, I updated the code from your example, but I'm still having a little issue. I want to start the spin animation immediately on hover, and could you see why I lose the dance animation when the cursor is out?

Comment: Try the updated code. Since the animation runs on hover, once the cursor is out, the animation ends

Comment: is that possible when the animation dance ends have the same effect scale down as when the cursor is hover it thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering)

Answer (score 0):

```
i am try this code and it works . why you comment the animation !

 .full-rounded-link:hover::before,.full-rounded-link:hover:before {
 transform: scale(1) ;
 animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
 }
 
 @keyframes spin { 
  0% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(180deg);
 }
 100% {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-180deg);
 }
 }
```